# How to call defaultExportCsv() of ReactJS material-table from the overriden export function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-table

I'm a beginner in reactjs. I'm handling material-table ([material-table.com](https://material-table.com/)) which should be capable of download data with the custom filename with the current timestamp. This can be solved by assigning the desired filename to the property `options.exportFileName` in `<MaterialTable>`. However, this timestamp will contain time when the page rendered, but I need the timestamp when the export button was clicked.

I was thinking if I can achieve this by calling `defaultExportCsv` from the overridden export function after setting the file name like below:

```js
function TableExport({model}) {
  const handleExportCsv = () => {
    options.exportFileName = 'filename_' + moment().format('YYYY-MM-DDTHHmmss');
    // calling defaultExportCsv here
  }

  return ( <
    MaterialTable columns = {
      [{
          title: 'ID',
          field: 'id'
        },
        {
          title: 'Name',
          field: 'name'
        },
      ]
    }
    data = {
      model
    }
    title = "Title"
    options = {
      {
        columnsButton: true,
        exportButton: true,
        actionsColumnIndex: -1,
        exportCsv: handleExportCsv,
      }
    }
    />
  );
}
```

I'm unable to call `defaultExportCsv()` from the `handleExportCsv()`, can somebody help me in this regard ?

Answer (score 2):

You can write your own exportCsv callback fn but then you are responsible for generating CSV data for exporting also.

Maybe you can find the following useful. For data exporting you can use the same library as in component MaterialTable. First, don't forget to install the library:

```
npm install --save filefy
```

And import library

```
const _filefy = require("filefy");
```

Inside functional component define fn for exporting data into CSV format:

```
  const exportCsv = (allColumns, allData) => {
    const columns = allColumns.filter(columnDef => columnDef["export"] !== false);
    const exportedData = allData.map(rowData => columns.map(columnDef => rowData[columnDef.field]));
    new _filefy.CsvBuilder('filename_' + moment().format('YYYY-MM-DDTHHmmss'))
      .setDelimeter(';')
      .setColumns(columns.map(columnDef => columnDef.title))
      .addRows(exportedData)
      .exportFile();
  }
```

Inside MaterialTable connect exportCsv

```
<MaterialTable
...
      options={
        {
...
          exportButton: true,
          exportCsv,
        }
      }
```

Comment: Hey thanks for answering. Since I was just appending the current time-stamp to the file name before saving it as CSV, I wanted to make use of `defaultExportCSV` by having an external call. I knew what you have suggested but I felt it as code redundancy. Turns out that it's an issue in the Material Table, I have raised it in their repo [here](https://github.com/mbrn/material-table/issues/1806)
By the way, I have resolved it with your approach as of now. Thanks