# Download the Detail Panel Data with all other data from export csv data in material-table

Tags: reactjs, material-table

I have created a table using material-table, where I have used 2 Detail Panels, also I have used export to csv option from material-table. While downloading the csv all data is downloaded except the data in detail panel. I want to get all the data including from detail panels into csv. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Hello @Pranav101py, have you managed to do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the custom csvExport. In this custom function you can map fields to modify the default export. I'm pretty sure it's not possible to export pivot tables.

Please, take a look at how exportCsv is implemented in [material-table library](https://github.com/mbrn/material-table/blob/5e9ef9affbc83db80301c4edee4306aabcc3701f/src/components/m-table-toolbar.js)

Follow the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61559548/10128925)